# Visual Studio 2022 Xamarin boot emulator with Live Share

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, xamarin.forms, android-emulator, visual-studio-liveshare

We are trying with a friend to write a mobile application (Xamarin.Forms).
Using Live Share we are connected and can co-write code and stuff. But at the same time, debugging works only on the side of the creator. The emulator itself was launched, but the application is visible only in the main group. Tried all the settings and gave permission for everything in options.LiveShare. Is there any way to use this app?

Comment: which vs version you are using?

Answer (score 0):

According to this [thread](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/vs-live-share-xamarin-debugging-not-working/195123) , VS2019 still doesn't allow shared debugging of Xamarin sessions.You may want to post an feature request here https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/live-share/issues?q=